# Does an app running in debug from android studio register intents. Trying to launch from NFC tag

Tags: android, nfc

I am attempting to have an app automatically load on detection of a NFC tag. Can someone advise when an apps intent is actually registered with the operating system i.e. will an app ran from the android debugger fire from an intent, or does the app need to be fully installed (APK) before the intent can be searched for and the app launched.

Any info or help in this generic scenario would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

When you install from Android Studio via the debug App button, you are doing a normal install and the Manifest with any NFC Intents are registered as normal.

But when you debug the App via the Button it not only installs the App, it starts the App and Attaches the debugger to the App.

Thus you have to shut the App down to trigger the launch via NFC on a real phone and then the debugger won't be attaced automatically to this new process, you have to do that manually (Use the "Run" -> "Attach Debugger to Android Process" menu items)

Comment: Thanks so much, I cant up-vote this but please mark as accepted answer.

Comment: Hi, only you can mark as accepted answer.

Comment: The only problem is that's impossible to debug the intent handler itself. Maybe the Flash could do it. A normal human just can't attach the debugger fast enough. Crap.